# ¿Como podria ejecutar dinamicamente una clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en donde en el archivo de despliegue, llamo un modulo y una clase con su nombre para ejecutar tal clase como controlador o backend de la pagina llamada.
Pasa que el nombre y el modulo de la clase varia segun un dato enviado por parámetros.
Ya tengo la importación del modulo, usando el importlib.import_module
Solo que esto no me permite acceder a las clases y ejecutarlas de manera dinamica.
Lo hago pensando que la clase tendría el mismo nombre y siempre habra una función especifica que se ejecutoria.
La idea es mandar el nombre del proyecto que quiero ejecutar y el nombre del controlador.
La clase que existe dentro del controlador tendría el mismo nombre y siempre tendría una clase llamada "principal" la cual tendría toda la funcionalidad principal del controlador

```
def exec(project, controller):

    validation = import_module("validation.project"))

    if validation.exist_project(project):

        module = import_module(project + "." + controller)

        execution_response = module.principal()
        return execution_response
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Pero lo que tienes en ese código parece ser justamente lo que quieres lograr, ¿no? ¿Qué te falta?

Comment: Te aconsejo re-pensar el como estas tratando de resolver el problema de nombres dinamicos. Creo que hacer un import dinamico de modulos es algo complicado y cercano a las malas practicas de Python, cuando en la practica pueden tener varias clases dentro un mismo modulo y registrar sus nombres mediante algun diccionario key:value y luego instanciar las clases por las llaves del diccionario.

Comment: Sii, finalmente me decante por crear una "libreria" de urls en donde almaceno los nombres o key y la clase que quiero desplegar. Esto funciono bastante bien. Y lo de jugar con variables dinamicas es un juego que me traigo de PHP, por eso trate de probarlo ahora aprendiendo python.